# Custom Button to be visible only for one profile in a view

Tags: custom-button

I have a requirement  for n no of closure of cases,where i have a created a visual force page ,apex cotroller and and custom button Named as "Num CLOSE".Now we would like to have this custom button "Num CLOSE " to be visible only for one profile in a view .

Any idea or suggestions very much appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean custom button? JS custom button or VF commandbutton?

Answer (score 1):

```
<apex:commandButton value="Go" rendered="{!$Profile.Name = 'Profile Name'}"/>
```